# Should I memorise surahs even if I don't understand them?

Tags: quran-memorization

Is there any ruling/advice on learning Surah's even if we don't understand them?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, one should at least memorize a few in order to say the prayers since it's mandatory to say the prayers in Arabic. Surah Fateha at the least.

Other than that there is no obligation to memorize them, although memorizing them has it's own benefits and usages e.g. the four *quls*.

Comment: Thank you. 
Q: What are the are the benefits and usages in general, and for the 'four qul's'?

Comment: In general it depend on the surah. e.g. reciting surah-ikhlas thrice is said to have the benefit of reciting the whole Quran. Four *quls* is for divine prevention against evil magic. And if one has memorized it then they could recite them whenever they want to. Plus AFAIK memorizing the verse of the Quran is considered as a good deed.